# Maximum Image Uri Length in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, uri

Does anyone know what the Maximum URL length is in Silverlight (version 4 if it matters)?  I know it is 2048 and basically infinite for Firefox (the two environments I have tested in), but Image requests fail for long Uri's.  Anyone know the magic number (is it 256 the max filepath length?)  It is considerably shorter than the 2048 for IE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [.NET framework library for Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492(VS.95).aspx) The `Uri` scheme can be 1024 while a complete `Uri` can be up to 65519 characters long. This is valid for both v3 and v4.

Hope this gives you some guidance.

**EDIT**

Okay, well after long testing, I managed to track down the limit for an image URL.

The scheme refers to the `http` part.

The whole `URI` cannot be longer than **2047** after which it seems to not load the image anymore. However, I could not find any official reasoning behind it.

The fact that you are getting `AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR` exceptions does not have anything to do with the length of the `URI`.

You can check however, if there are any illegal characters in your URI:

- You can find the reserved characters in [RFC2369](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html) and see their web counterparts at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

I also found that if the link is placed in the XAML, you have to replace the '&' sign with its '%26' counterpart.

Comment: Then why do images with URI with URI's longer than 1024 fail with AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR?

Comment: Maybe 2047 is in bytes? If so, and we assume two bytes per character, then we get 1024.